# php apache forbidden error on multiple input field data submit

Tags: php, apache

I'm getting this weird forbidden error when I post form data. I have this form  which has multiple input fields. It works fine till it reaches 200 input fields. When it exceeds 200 fields I get 403 forbidden error. I've set the post max size to 100M and max input vars 100000 but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: 200 input fields , isn't that a bit off the track? Think of a user who has to fill these fields. Shouldn't you split these fields into multiple forms (Something like a wizard)

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Start dumping and dying your super variables. It seems your not catching something in your code. Please post your work.

Comment: @Satya: They're chart of accounts uploading from excel and other sources.

Comment: @Mike: Can't find anything in the error log

Comment: Are you using `method=GET`? You may be running into a limit on the size of a URL. Use `method=POST` and there's effectively no limit.

Comment: @Heman maybe you're not looking in the right place. Or maybe logging is disabled. Try `phpinfo()` and look for the `error_log` value and make sure it's set and check that file.

Comment: @KLVTZ: same code works fine in the local server. Not sure if it's server configuration

Comment: @Barmar good thinking, but wouldn't that just truncate the values sent through $_GET?

Comment: @Barmar: i'm using POST

Comment: @Heman there's your answer. Your remote is not working because it does not contain the same settings as your local. If everything is working fine locally, then you will need to adjust your settings remotely.

Comment: @KLVTZ: what specific settings should I change?

Comment: @Heman, you said you adjusted your max_input_vars locally or remotely? If locally, then do the same remotely.

Comment: @KLVTZ: I've changed it on the sever too

Comment: @Mike: error_log is fine. but there's no error recorded for this issue

Comment: @Heman sorry, I was wrong. Check your web server's error log. If it were a PHP error it would change it to a 500 response code, not 403.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to help. 403 seems rather suspicious. What does your stack look like... is this hosted?

Comment: a 403 forbidden error under this context seems that you may have some type of protection enabled for long query strings, or something of that sort.

Comment: @Mike: It says File does not exist

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right place? File does not exist is a 404 error.

Comment: @user602525: Yes it's hosted. What information you need?

Comment: @Mike: yes I'm checking from cpanel.

Comment: @Heman who is your host? My goodness, if I can say, this entire answer and question is becoming a discussion and not what is originally purpose for a comment section.

Comment: @KLVTZ: it's a local company (hostingbay)

Comment: @HemanYou expressed that you are using cPanel for the majority of your adjustments. You can navigate to your cPanel's software/services and should select PHP config. From there, you will have to adjust your PHP.ini file. That file is the key to fixing your problem on a remote hosting that is hostingbay.

Comment: @KLVTZ Unfortunately, I don't have permission to edit the server PHP.ini. BTW I have added custom PHP.ini in the directory. So when I run phpinfo it appears all the custom settings. I'm sure it's something to do with the server configuration but not sure which one it is.

Comment: @Heman, so it applies the .ini file? In other words, are you still experiencing your problem?

Comment: @kLVTZ: yes. it hasn't solved the prob. It's so weird.

Comment: @Heman I really want us to get to the bottom of this problem, have you tried the selected answer from this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447454/apache-giving-403-forbidden-errors

Comment: @KLVTZ, Yes I've been looking for answers everywhere. nothing works out so far. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @Heman My pleasure in helping. If you do end up solving this very odd problem, be sure to post it as an answer for reference -you can answer your own questions.

Comment: @KLVTZ, sure I will. BTW I have no clue on this. Dunno why it's not even creating a record on error log.

Comment: Hello Guys, problem has been solved. I contacted the host and they've disable mod_security on our account and it works. BTW, i'm not sure  if it's safe to disable mod_sec. Anyway, thanks everyone for commenting on this. Good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem has been solved. I contacted the host and they've disabled mod_security on our account and it works. BTW, i'm not sure  if it's safe to disable mod_sec. Anyway, thanks everyone for commenting on this. Good day!

Comment: Good (He)man!
I'm not surprised that this would be the final issue for your host.