# Digital Ocean Deployment Laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel, mcrypt, digital-ocean

I'm having a bit of trouble deploying a new laravel app to my digital ocean account. I followed the steps outline in this tutorial:
http://davidmyers.name/post/laravel-on-digital-ocean

Yet I find that upon trying to access the index page, I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.scheduleify.com Port 80
```

However, I am able to access PHPMyAdmin just fine by going to www.scheduleify.com/phpmyadmin

I have a feeling this has something to do with setting the default directory to the public folder.

In the article linked above, the author mentions that upon opening the file: 
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

One should see the following two lines:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
```

This is my entire file, which seems to lack one of them (I've already modified the one that was there accordingly):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /root/scheduleify/public

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host 

only   
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Another thing I noticed: If I ssh into my root directory, and go into the cloned repository/project folder, and try to run php artisan, I get the error:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

However, if I run the command mcrypt from the same directory, I get:

```
mcrypt: Encrypted data will not be written to a terminal.
Redirect the output instead.
Use the --help parameter for more help.
```

Which suggests mcrypt is working. Any input/help is greatly appreciated. I'm very close to giving up, I've been going at this for hours and getting nowhere.

---

Update: The first error was resolved.

The 403 error remains; Checking the apache2 logs, I found this error:

```
[Fri Jan 16 09:38:31.855624 2015] [core:error] [pid 5641]   
(13)Permission denied: [client [removed]] AH00035: access to / denied 
(filesystem path '/root/scheduleify') because search permissions are 
missing on a component of the path
```

Comment: maybe check `Require` directive in your virtual host and httpd.conf file. In my case in a virtual host it's set to `Require all granted`

Comment: What is the droplet OS?

Comment: Droplet OS is LAMP on Ubuntu. Anyhow I resolved the issue, I'm waiting a day to chose my own comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem:

`You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

This is generally an issue with permissions. eg root owns /root/scheduleify and the web server (generally www-data on ubuntu & debian) can't read that directory.

`chown -R www-data: /root/scheduleify`

If this does fix the problem you will need to re-run this command every time you upload new files as root.

For the second problem:

`Mcrypt PHP extension required.`

can be fixed with:

`apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

finally restart apache.

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: It seems that neither of the problems were fixed :\. I ran the chown command and the 403 still persists. What's more confusing is that the mcrypt command didn't work, even though it was in fact missing php5-mcrypt. I still get the same error when attempting to run php artisan. Any ideas?

Comment: Update- I found this article resolved my mcrypt issue: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/installing-laravel-on-a-ubuntu-14-04-droplet . Now only the 403 error remains - thanks for your help so far!!!

Comment: ah yes, the `php5enmod` command. for the 403 errors, i would check the apache error logs to see if they have any more information. also more help can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447454/apache-giving-403-forbidden-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was placing the app inside of the root directory... This is a bad idea and would require additional apache configuration.

By moving the project out of the root folder (root/project) into the var/www/html/project directory, and going through the same process outlined in the article, I was able to get the app to work!