# Getting 403 error for css, js files and images on public server in joomla

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-403

I have made a custom theme for joomla, its working all fine on localhost but when i put it on public server i get 403 error for css, js files and images. I have checked the permissions they seem to be alright as folders have 755 and files have 644 permission. I dont know what is wrong, my .htaccess file is like this:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddHandler application/x-hg-php53 .php
```

Answer (score 0):

The error 403 it's the : **403 Forbidden Status**.

Which it means you don't have the permission to read the resource.

So It could mean that or you don't have the permissions or the owner is not correct.

If you checked the permissions already it may be is the owner.

You can find more info here : [Apache Giving 403 Forbidden Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447454/apache-giving-403-forbidden-errors).