# Forbidden 403 Access URL API in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Good afternoon, let me ask
I created a service API using Laravel, but one of the API urls when I sent the response parameter was 403 or Forbidden. even though before it was fine, it worked smoothly. And I raised it to the server instead it became Forbide. Anyone know why? thank you for answering

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok on local and getting a forbidden error on the server, the problem might be caused by the webserver application. please take a look at  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447454/apache-giving-403-forbidden-errors).